# Restricting XQuery to XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xqilla

I've got an app that manages collections of XML files and allows querying using XPath, to allow users to view subsets of collections that match an XPath query.

For various technical reasons, I'm switching to an XQuery engine. I understand that XQuery is a superset of XPath. However, I don't want full XQuery functionality because users may use it to construct new XML objects that don't match my DTD and can't be displayed by my SVG-based viewer.

Can I easily validate query strings as XPath and hand them off to the XQuery engine? Or can I convert them in a simple way?

(I'm using C++ and switching to XQilla.)

Comment: This is an strange requeriment. If you want to forbade node constructors (XQuery) and scalar items construction (XPath 2.0) maybe you should use an XPath 1.0 engine instead. Otherwise you would need to parse the expression and ban those having such constructions. Other solution would be to filter the resulting expression for those node instances belonging to the source document...

Comment: @Alejandro: We're moving from XQuery only because that's implemented in an optimized way in Berkeley DB XML, our new storage engine. Our users expect XPath, though, and the added expressive power may hurt once we decide on a client-server architecture (I understand XQuery is Turing complete).

Comment: You could use my XPath 2.0 parser, written entirely in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQilla did turn out to have an XPath 2.0 parser, so I'm using that now.

Comment: Glad you found this in the end! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find an XPath 2.0 parser that works in your environment, you could consider converting the query to XQueryX and running queries against it to check that it doesn't use any undesired features.

Comment: I have an XPath 2.0 parser. The problem is that it doesn't seem to distinguish between XPath 2.0 and XQuery. XQueryX sounds like even more complications...

Comment: +1 Dr. Kay, this is an excellent answer. @larsmans [here](http://www.w3.org/2005/qt-applets/xqueryApplet.html) you have the W3C applet for translations from XQuery to XQueryX

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion, though I did find the XPath 2.0 parser in the end.